# Rendering subclass returning superclass

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I´m rendering a class with a class attribute like this

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DefineObjectForm<T extends Parcel> {
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefineObjectForm.class);

@Getter
@Setter
private T  parcel;

}
```

I define the Parcel as generic because sometimes can be UserDefine and sometimes GlobalParcel, both extends Parcel

I´m setting to that parcel class a UserDefined class

```
   DefineObjectForm dof = new DefineObjectForm();
   dof.setParcel(new UserDefined());
```

Now I´m rendering to my view this entity.

But, as soon as I commit my form with this modelAndAttribute model I receive Parcel instead UserDefined.

What I´m missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type in the instantiation:

```
DefineObjectForm<UserDefined> dof = new DefineObjectForm<UserDefined>();
```

Comment: I did DefineObjectForm<? extends Parcel> sometimes can be GlobalParcel instead UserDefined. But does not work the ModelAndAttribute return PArcel

Comment: Well, then you won't get any more information than that it is a `Parcel`. `T` is defined when you declare the class.

Comment: Ok but even if I do when I create the DefineObject, what about when I commit my modelAndAttribute, I´m looking for a mechanism to reuse the method to retrieve a DefineObjectForm with GlobalParcel or UserDefined. When I debug after create the DEfineObjectForm, I can see that inside there are a instance of UserDefine. But when I retrieve in my controller the modelAndAttribute only Parcel is there